# Stackoverflow error when loading list in JPA

Tags: jpa, stack-overflow

I am using JSF 2.1 and have a problem loading lists containing huge amounts of data.
The data is fetched from a database via JPA, which basically looks like this:
(just the relevant part, omitting getters and setters)

```
public class HostController {

    private List<Host> allHosts;
    @Inject
    private HostService hostService;

    public void beforeRenderLoadList(final ComponentSystemEvent event) {
        allHosts = hostService.findAll();
    }
}
```

This code is used in a metaevent `preRenderView` on the xhtml-page.

It is working for smaller amounts of data, but since the original table contains about 6500 entries, it throws a stackoverflow error.

Is there any way to lazy load this list or to work around the error?

Comment: Google solved it by using pagination. Have you considered it? Which human in the world would ever need to see 6500 entries at once without filtering (by a search keyword) and/or pagination (so that only a subset can be retrieved from the DB)? Additional benefit is that it's much, much faster to retrieve and display only 10 records instead of 6500. By the way, this problem has nothing to do with JSF, you'd have had exactly the same problem when using another frontend to use the JPA code. To get better answers, please post the stack overflow error and the actual JPA code.

Comment: @BalusC The query is basically "SELECT h FROM hosts h". My datatables work with pagination and lazy loading - works fine.
The content I'm talking about here, is supposed to be displayed in a selectOneMenu. Is there a way to lazy load that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers!

The problem has finally been solved by setting each entity's FetchType to LAZY!

Answer (score 0):

What we normally do in such situations is providing for **pagination** of data. It is clear that this situation in fact *must be solved* when data volume and/or user load is high.

This basically means that you will have the method that will accept `from` and `to`, or `size` parameters to account for number of records to get from the database:

```
public List<Host> getHosts(int from, int to) {
    hostService.findAllIn(int from, int to);
}
```

For example, `Query#setFirstResult` and `Query#setMaxResults` of [Query class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) can be used to achieve that functionality within your service.

The pagination in view can be handled either by `<h:commandButton>`s via POST, or `<h:link>`s and `<f:param>`/`<f:viewParam>` via GET. Rough examples:

```
<h:commandButton value="Next" action="#{bean.next}"/>
```

with a view scoped bean

```
private int from;
private int to;
private int step;
private int page;
public String next() {
    page++;
    from = (page - 1) * step + 1;
    to = page * step;
    return null;
}
```

or

```
<h:link value="Next" outcome="viewhost">
    <f:param name="page" value="#{bean.page + 1}" />
</h:link>
```

Note that increasing memory size is not a solution to the problem, but essentially a delay of its consequences.

Alternatively, you may use some component library like Primefaces with default paging capabilities, like [`<p:dataTable>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf).